# Spark MLlib libsvm issues with data

Tags: scala, libsvm, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying with the demo in http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/mllib-linear-methods.html
with the example via scala version.
I run the demo it was worked fine but when I changed data and the step of train it just error with

```
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 21, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1447 bytes)
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 22, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1447 bytes)
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 21)
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 22)
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_7_1 locally
15/05/05 16:32:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 22)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.HingeGradient.compute(Gradient.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:190)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_7_0 locally
15/05/05 16:32:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 21)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.HingeGradient.compute(Gradient.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:190)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/05 16:32:02 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 22, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.HingeGradient.compute(Gradient.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:190)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/05/05 16:32:02 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 21) on executor localhost: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (-1) [duplicate 1]
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 12
15/05/05 16:32:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 12 failed: treeAggregate at GradientDescent.scala:189, took 0.032101 s
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 22, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.HingeGradient.compute(Gradient.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.GradientDescent$$anonfun$runMiniBatchSGD$1$$anonfun$1.apply(GradientDescent.scala:190)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:988)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

https://github.com/hermitD/temp here's my test data file
I've use it to train with libsvm-tools under linux and it works! and exam format with libsvm python tool it shows ok. just don't know why it error.

Comment: In the past I faced this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 and finally solve that with the "^M" ERROR ,just delete the "Win Enter" it was worded,but so weird it could not work for now.

Answer (score 1):

After do some tests,finally I solve it.I wrote here for other people who met this question.
here's a example of data format error I faced

0 0:0 1:0 2:1
1 1:1 3:2

the data for 0:0 and 1:0/1:1 is the reason for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.If someone who faced the same question just delete them from u past data or update it.
Since it was worked in libsvm-tools,so I guess in spark MLlib it just implements a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the libSVM format and MLlib. In my case, the first feature was labeled as 0 instead of 1. XGBoost had no problem with that, but both Weka and Spark MLlib failed with the same `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

The solution in this case is to sum 1 to each feature to start with 1 instead of 0. The easiest way to do it in Python is:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file, dump_svmlight_file

X, y = load_svmlight_file('example.libsvm')
X.indices = (X.indices + 1)
dump_svmlight_file(X, y, 'fixed.libsvm')
```